# Perform a search in Visual Studio only on files that have been recently modified

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ide, replace

I was wondering if there is a way for Visual Studio's built-in search to only look in files that have been modified in a certain time frame.

I think it would be very convenient, especially when working with a large codebase where you don't really need to search for certain things in ancient code (or even code older than, say a month, even a week).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Not in Visual Studio 2010.  Also not in Visual Studio 2012 (which includes the Quick Find feature from the Productivity Power Tools extension.)

You'll probably need to make do with [Windows Search](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-findsearch-files-by-date-and-size/) or a third party tool like [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home).